# Scanning in from a text file

Tags: c, encryption

For my decryption program I must be able to scan in a substitution table from a text file that has an encrypted text right after the substitution table at the very bottom. I must use that substitution table to decrypt the message. So now I believe that the best way to do that would be to scan in the substitution table first and store both columns into 2 different arrays, then scan the encrypted message the the end afterwards. However, I have no idea how to do that.

I do know that the substitution table will be no longer then 62 lines (26+26+10) no matter what. However, the encrypted message can have as many lines as it wants.

A encrypted text file (projectinput.txt) looks generally like this:

```
a m
b n
  etc...
z q
A P
B O
  etc...
Z X
0 5
1 4
  etc...
9 0
Ekrmov 04320
SDFVSDFV
```

Current Decryption Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char input[256];
char encrypted[256];
char line[100];
int c;
int j;
int main(){
FILE *file1=fopen("projectoutput.txt", "r");
FILE *file2=fopen("projectinput.txt", "w");

    while(fgets(line,100,file1)!=NULL){
    sscanf(line, "%c %c", input, encrypted);
    fprintf(file2, "%c %c\n", input[j], encrypted[j]);
    }


        while((c=fgetc(file1))!=EOF){
            int i=0;
            while(encrypted[i]!=c){
                i++;
            }

            fputc(input[i], file2);

        }

return 0;

}
```

I just updated my code, my while loop that contains the fgets is able to store the substitution table into 2 arrays, however, it also stores the encrypted message at the bottom as well. I want to stop the while loop from reading in lines past 62, how should I do that?

Comment: You should decompose you program into smaller parts. You have basically three different problems : 1. scanning the subsitution table into two different arrays, 2. reading the encrypted text character by character and 3. transforming an encrypted character into a decrypted character.

Comment: actually i have the decrypt the character part already figured out. so yeah i have 2 problems splitting the substitution table into 2 arrays and scanning in the encrypted text.

Comment: Since `encrypted[]` has fewer than 256 members, suggest testing `i` to insure you do not go off the deep end.  `if (i >= sizeof(input)) { puts("error Msg"); exit(1); }` in the `while` loop after `i++`

Comment: For the 2 array part: Loop 62 times and use `fgetc` 4 times. Store the first `fgetc` to array1 and third `fgetc` to array2. (The input text must be exactly as you posted eg char-space-char-\n)

Comment: could you show me an example as to how to use fgetc 4 times to get the individual characters and then store them into 2 different arrays

Comment: You should not destroy a question when it has answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < 62: i++){
    input[i] = fgetc(file1);
    fgetc(file1);
    encrypted[i] = fgetc(file1);
    fgetc(file1);
}
```

EDIT: try this

```
char *buff;
char *decoded;
long file_Size;

fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
file_Size = ftell(file1);
fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_SET);

buff = malloc(file_Size * sizeof(char));
decoded = malloc((file_Size - 62 * 4) * sizeof(char));

//writing all text file to buff array. It is faster and the array is easier to  
//manipulate
fread(buff, sizeof(unsigned char), file_Size, file1);

j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 62; i++){
    input[i] = buff[j];
    encrypted[i] = buff[j + 2];
    j += 4;
}

//move encrypted message to decoded array
memmove(decoded, &buff[62 * 4], file_Size - 62 * 4);

//decoding process
for(i = 0; i < file_Size - 62 * 4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 62; j++){
        if(decoded[i] == '\n' || decoded[i] == ' '){break;}
        if(decoded[i] == input[j]){decoded[i] = encrypted[j]; break;}
    }
}
```

Write `decoded` to file2 and

```
free(decoded);
free(buff);
```

valter

Comment: ty that works, how would you suggest scanning in the encrypted code at the bottom and then comparing it with the substitution table?

Comment: 1) Why 4?  64 seems arbitrary too but I see OP says 62. 2) Why is `fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_SET);` not needed?

Comment: @chux You are right about the second (corrected it). I cant understand the first one though.

Comment: valter could you explain to me for loop thats scanning in the 2 arrays?, how does it know to scan the first character in the line and then the third character in the line?

Comment: @user3473994 The scanning for the two arrays works because of the input file format, which is `character-space-character-\n`(as you posted). So it is always the first and the third character for each of the 62 lines. If it is not the case eg you have more spaces then yes, it doesnt work. You have to provide me the format of the file, does it change or is it the way you posted it?

Comment: no it works perfectly, thats also how i thought it worked. i just simply wanted confirmation. ty

Answer (score 1):

Two ways that you can do this:

- Read each of the 62 lines one-by-one. You can use `fgets()` for this. For each line, split by the whitespace token using `strtok`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ and assign each character to the appropriate array.
- Read in the characters one by one and assign each character to its appropriate array based on read order.

Comment: i just updated my code, my while loop that contains the fgets is able to store the substitution table into 2 arrays, however, it also stores the encrypted message at the bottom as well. I want to stop the while loop from reading in lines past 62, how should i do that?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for pointing out the error! It was my mistake. Edited my answer.

Comment: @user3473994 You can terminate the loop after 62 reads by setting the condition appropriately.

Comment: please explain, im not sure what to do to cancel it. i tried doing an if statement

Comment: @user3473994 valter's answer is very good and more illuminating.